# Возникло исключение загрузки типа

Tags: c#

Получаю данную ошибку при использование кода

Typeloadexception : A type load exception has occurred

```
IOrderedEnumerable<ModuleContainer> OrderedModuleSelector = from x in Plugins orderby , x.Plugin.Name select x;
```

Что я делаю не так?

цель подгрузка библиотек[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По идее так должно быть: `IOrderedEnumerable<ModuleContainer> OrderedModuleSelector = from x in Plugins orderby x.Plugin.Name select x;` Т.е. без запятой

Comment: Все равно получаю данную ошибку

Comment: приложенная картинка показывает, что ошибка только в запятой

Comment: @Grundy я ее убрал уже - все равно та же ошибка

Comment: @Azymok, какая та же? На картинке ошибок нет. Добавляй вместо картинки полный текст ошибки со stacktrace и кодом, выполняя который ты получаешь указанную ошибку.

Comment: @Grundy я же писал что за ошибка - Typeloadexception : A type load exception has occurred

Comment: @Azymok, этого недостаточно. Нужен **полный** текст, плюс stacktrace и, возможно, содержимое `innerException`

Comment: from x in Plugins orderby , у тебя даже на скрине запятая красным подсвечивается, после order by указать объект нужно

Comment: @user2455111 я говорил, запятую я убрал,но ошибка осталась

Comment: @Azymok давай новый скрин с новой ошибкой. Какого типа Plugins?

Comment: @user2455111 ошибка та же - Typeloadexception : A type load exception has occurred Pluigins тип ReadOnlyCollection<ModuleContainer>

Comment: @Azymok это ошибка связана со сборкой, видимо ее не удалось подгрузить. Можно попробовать скомпилировать проект на другом компе или выгружать или подгружать поочередно сборки, т.к. стек трейса от вас видимо мы не увидим

Comment: @user2455111 я не знаю как вам дать этот "стек трейс"

Comment: @Azymok попробуйте сочетание ctrl+shift+e (e - английская)

Comment: @Azymok или же нажать на copy exception details to the clipboard http://imgur.com/a/4n3YO

Comment: @user2455111 ошибки нету в консоли vs - ошибка появляется когда уже запускаю программу и она доходит до строчки,которая в самом вопросе

Comment: @Azymok причем тут консоль? Если возникает ошибка, дебаггер сам показывает это окно, откуда можно скопировать детали ошибки

Comment: @user2455111z я же говорю,что ошибка появляется в консоли программы, а не в VS